# Difference between zuerst and erste

Tags: learning

What is the difference between the words `zuerst` and `erste` in meaning?

Can it be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Zuerst" is used as "doing something first, before something else". It can be shortened to "erst". 
"Erste", however, means "the first" and it can only be used if a woman is first. 
Therefore, these two are not interchangeable as the meaning is completely different.

Comment: How about ```Der Erste``` and ```Das Erste``` (First german television channel)? Does the gender really matter?

Comment: Und was ist mit "Erste Erfahrungen sammelte ..."

Answer (score 3):

**Zuerst** is an adverb
 **Erst**(-e/-es/-er/-en/-em) is a count word or maybe an adjective

Answer (score 2):

For Example:

Zuerst gehe ich Milch einkaufen. --> First, I go to buy milk.

If you want to count something you have to use erste.

Das Erste, das Zweite, das Dritte.... -> The first, the second, the third....
Das erste Haus -> the first house

So erste is used as adjective.

You can exchange *zuerst* with *als erstes* to keep the same meaning in the first example.

Comment: "Das Erste" sieht aber ein wenig wie ein Substantiv aus.

Comment: I am wondering about the sentence: "Erst die Arbeit, dann das Spiel". (My dad always said this to me :) ) Why is it not "Zuerst"?